# powershell script- clear event log 'access to the "computername" computer is denied' error

Tags: windows, powershell, logging, automation

I'm trying to run a powershell script to automatically clear the system, security, application logs.

I keep getting an error when trying  to use the clear-log function
Error:'access to the "computername" computer is denied'
its listed as a win32 exception error

```
clear-eventlog -logname application, security, system
```

I've already set powershell to always run as admin. I'd like to be able to solve for this from within the ps1 script file if possible

Comment: Not enough info. How are you running it? Local, scheduled task, remotely, invoke-command, etc

Comment: locally from a .ps1 file